# Show a number in boxes Rdlc Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

i need to show Field Value i.e each number inside a bordered box you can see picture attached 
[image]

Comment: You can use a string indexer to pull individual characters from a string - you'd have to count backwards using `len(string)` to grab each digit though, and you'd need a box with a different expression for each digit. 

Add a custom function to your report code and pass it the string and a negative index to tell it which character you wish to pull into the box. Handle the index out of range by returning `""` (a blank string)

Comment: can you please write a sample expression thx

Comment: You could use the code from this *almost* duplicate answer, but it assumes the value will always be the same length and that it will fill from the left - I assume you want to fill from the right - I'll provide some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB, you can use the `Chars` property on a string which gives you an array you can index into

In your custom report code add the following function:

```
Public Function GetDigit(value as String, position as integer) as String
  If len(value) + position < 0 then
    return ""
  End If

  Return value.Chars(len(value) + position)
End Function
```

Now you can create a table or a series of textboxes - in each one you must specify a negative index (the amount of characters from the end of the string to count back from)

e.g.

In the last box

`=Code.GetDigit(Fields!AdviceNoteID.Value, -1)`

In the box before this

`=Code.GetDigit(Fields!AdviceNoteID.Value, -2)`

And so on.

This should give you a right-aligned figure which only shows 1 digit per box. It will return a blank value for any digit that doesn't exist.

**Example:**

[image: example]